# How to avoid the 'no-param-reassign' rule with a input's handleChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, styled-components

I'm working to build a React Textarea that auto grows/shrinks as the user types. I've built my component inspired by this codepen: https://codepen.io/Libor_G/pen/eyzwOx

While I have this working nicely, I'm getting an es-lint error I'm unsure how to correctly resolve. eslint is not liking that I'm using the event param in the handleChange function.

What is the right way to resolve this?

My REACT UIC:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const TEXTAREA_LINE_HEIGHT = 24;
const PADDING = 16;

const StyledTextArea = styled.textarea`
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: ${PADDING}px;

  line-height: ${TEXTAREA_LINE_HEIGHT}px;
  font-size: 17px;
`;


class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      rows: 1,
      minRows: 1,
      maxRows: 3,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { minRows, maxRows } = this.state;


    const previousRows = event.target.rows;
    event.target.rows = minRows; // reset number of rows in textarea

    const currentRows = Math.floor((event.target.scrollHeight - (PADDING * 2)) / TEXTAREA_LINE_HEIGHT);

    if (currentRows === previousRows) {
      event.target.rows = currentRows;
    }

    if (currentRows >= maxRows) {
      event.target.rows = maxRows;
      event.target.scrollTop = event.target.scrollHeight;
    }

    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
      rows: currentRows < maxRows ? currentRows : maxRows,
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    const {
      name,
      placeholder,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <StyledTextArea
        innerRef={(ref) => {
          this.textAreaRef = ref;
        }}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        rows={this.state.rows}
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

TextArea.defaultProps = {
  name: null,
  placeholder: null,
};

TextArea.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
};

export default TextArea;
```

Comment: it's because you're modifying dom attribute values of the `event.target`

Comment: You can either not assign the param to new values or disable the rule for function params like this `/*eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": false }]*/`
You can either add that inside the file at the top or add it in your .eslintrc file for a global effect.
Here is the documentation for that rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

Comment: I hate using es-lint ignore, is there a way to achieve the same rule without ignoring eslint? thx

Comment: @AnApprentice you can try assigning event to another variable in that case like doing `const ev = event` and use `ev` instead

Comment: @IbraheemAl-Saady wow that worked. thank you. please leave as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either disable the rule as I mentioned in my comment like the following:
`/*eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": false }]*/`

Or if you don't prefer to ignore eslint, you can assign your param to a new variable:

`const ev = event` and you can use ev instead of event.